# jQuery Mobile Transition not working

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to build a simple mobile app and it's my first time using jQuery Mobile
I followed tutorials online and i can't find what's wrong with my code :\

I'm trying to create 3 different pages with slide transition. Sliding works but without the transition.

When the view loads, it looks like i have this 'loading circle' stuck in the middle of the screen but i can't find what causing me errors and Eclipse's console is empty

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first app OMG</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Homepage menu and content -->
<div data-role="page" id="homepage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#homepage" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trending" data-transition="slide" data-icon="star">Trending</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bycategory" data-transition="slide" data-icon="bullets">Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h1>Latest Feeds</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Content of 'Home'..</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Trending posts menu and content -->
<div data-role="page" id="trending">

    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#homepage" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trending" data-transition="slide" data-icon="star">Trending</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bycategory" data-transition="slide" data-icon="bullets">Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h1>Most Visited</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Content of 'Trending'..</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Category filter menu and content -->
<div data-role="page" id="bycategory">

    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#homepage" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trending" data-transition="slide" data-icon="star">Trending</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bycategory" data-transition="slide" data-icon="bullets">Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h1>Categories</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Content of 'Categories'..</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is are my scripts-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Set first page to load to #homepage
    window.location.hash = 'homepage';
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});

$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
 if(event.type == 'swiperight') {
  var prevpage = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prev('div[data-role="page"]')[0].id;
      $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
       transition: 'slide',
       reverse: true
      });
 }

 if(event.type == 'swipeleft') {
  var nextpage = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.next('div[data-role="page"]')[0].id;
      $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {
       transition: 'slide',
       reverse: false
      });
 }
});
```

Comment: is it working in chrome, firefox, ie??

Comment: Just remove the window.location.hash = 'homepage'; and $.mobile.initializePage();. They are not needed. Homepage will automatically load as it is the first defined page in the document.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. I now tried it on explorer but it looks the same.. eznaker, i removed the hash code and now it works thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the first 'document.ready' function with the hash